# set publisher field in .rc file

Tags: winapi

I received message like

[image]

where I need set my Publisher Name in .rc (resource file) to show it in this window?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set the FileDescription and CompanyName fields of your [version resource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa381058%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Visual Studio:

Expand your project and right-click **Resource Files**. Select **Add** --> **Resource...** --> **Version**.

Fill out the version, publisher, and product name fields as you like.

This will create a new **.rc** file in the project with your metadata. Recompile and you're good.