# Changing "Publisher" information for a ".exe" file

Tags: publisher

**HOW I CAME ACROSS THIS**

I wrote code for a simple stopwatch which can also double up as a Rubik's cube timer. The source code and the executable are here:

[Cube timer](http://www.mediafire.com/?o7o8spk7kdqlu)

Anyway my doubt is not regarding this code(It works fine).

I downloaded the executable that I had uploaded to check if it worked fine and at that time I was greeted with this screen:

`Open file - security warning`

And under this dialogue box there was a field that said:

`Publisher : Unknown Publisher`

**SCREEN SHOT:**

[image: screenshot]

**DOUBT**

Is there some way programatically or otherwise by which I can change the `publisher` field?

**SPECS**

I have compiled the code with Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Express.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can easily change the publisher, either when linking/compiling by setting the [appropriate resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5460889/set-publisher-field-in-rc-file) for your project (e.g. *CompanyName*), or modifying the resources with a [resource editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4072455/windows-pe-resources).

Your problem is really that there is no [signature](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172240.aspx), so even if a publisher field is present it cannot be trusted.

You can find an example resource `rc` file near the end of http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa381058%28v=vs.85%29.aspx.

To add resources to your VC project check:

- [How do I embed version information into a windows binary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/975936/how-do-i-embed-version-information-into-a-windows-binary)
- [VC++ 2012: How to include version info from version.inc (maintained separately) into the .rc file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12821369/vc-2012-how-to-include-version-info-from-version-inc-maintained-separately)

The `.rc` file(s) will be compiled to binary (`.res`) and linked into your final executable.

To add or modify an existing executable, you should be able to use [this tool](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37133/Simple-Version-Resource-Tool-for-Windows) (login required, this will cause the signature to be invalid in an already signed binary of course).

The [Microsoft Authenticode documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537359%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) includes tutorials.

[CAcert.org](http://cacert.org/) will sign a certificate you can use, and have [instructions for getting started with Authenticode](http://wiki.cacert.org/Authenticode).

Sorry I can't be more helpful with VC, I don't use it, I usually using `mingw` and `make`, from some time ago targetting win32:

1. given a VERSIONINFO in a text `version.rc` file use `mingw32-windres` to compile it to a `.o` file (I actually had a bunch of .rc files, they were each `#include`-d in a single `resources.rc` so I only needed to run `windres` on that single file, and link a single extra object file)
2. include that `version.o` (or combined `resources.o`) in the final CC command, assuming compile and link to executable in one step
3. I also included `-lversion` when linking, AFAIR this was just because I used `GetFileVersionInfo()` for the code to check and display its own version in the 'About' dialog.

Comment: Sir, can you give me complete steps. I am not able to understand the documentation given on the links you gave

Comment: Added links to MS tutorials on Authenticode, and CAcert to for a certificate and their usage instructions.

Comment: @mr.spuratic, you wrote that you use mingw and make. I'm building a Win64 application using MinGW, and now I would like to set the publisher. My current exe has "Unknown publisher". Could you give me a hint how to create an exe with my publisher name using MinGW?

Comment: @ywiyogo, I have added what I remember, I no longer have that build environment...

Answer (score -1):

Make your program in a batch file, then using Advanced BAT to EXE Converter, convert it to EXE & fill out all of the fields. This sure helped me! :)

Comment: That doesn't work with the publisher field. The field needs a digital signature -_-